# Creating JasperReport reports based on elasticsearch datasource

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jasper-reports

Since 4 hours, I'm creating JasperReports through Java Code.
I have managed to generate pdf report based on postgreSQL.

I'm now trying to generate reports based on elasticsearch data with a simple main()

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Map<String, Object> parametres = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parametres.put("DATE_DEBUT", new Date());
        parametres.put("DATE_FIN", new Date(115, 8, 20));
        parametres.put("DATE_FIN_AFFICHAGE", new Date(115, 8, 20));
        parametres.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "rapports/");
        parametres.put("IMAGES_DIR", "rapports/");
        //JasperCompileManager.compileReport("rapports/rapport_mensuel.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jp =     JasperFillManager.fillReport("rapports/rapport_mensuel.jasper", parametres);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, "test.pdf");

    } catch (JRException e) {
      System.err.println("Exception Jasper " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

I have got this error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer
>   factory registered for the 'elasticsearch' language. at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRQueryExecuterUtils.getExecuterFactory(JRQueryExecuterUtils.java:114)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1108)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:689)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1281)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:900)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:152)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:464)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:300)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:757)
>   at fr.sigma.jasper.pdf.Main.main(Main.java:165)

I have found out an ElasticSearch plugin exists for JasperStudio (https://github.com/WedjaaOpen/ElasticJasper). It works perfectly fine in JasperStudio, however I want to export it into a Jar.

How can I generate my jar through JasperStudio ?